# Angular CLI: 12.2.0 "No overload matches this call."

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create an cart for an Angular project. I want to declare product as a Product but I am running into an error:
(Error message shown on: "(product: Product) => { ..."

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: PartialObserver | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(product: Product) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PartialObserver | undefined'.
> Property 'complete' is missing in type '(product: Product) => void' but required in type 'CompletionObserver'.
> Overload 2 of 5, '(next?: ((value: unknown) => void) | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(product: Product) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'product' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Product'.ts(2769)

My cart.components.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {

this.message.getMessage().subscribe((product: Product) => {

  this.cartItems.push({
    id: 1,
    productName: "string",
    qty: 1,
    price: 1
  })

  this.cartItems.forEach(item => {
    this.cartTotal += (item.qty * item.price)
  })
})
```

}

I want to push the product selected from the array(when clicking add to cart on the menu page). So instead of having "id: 1, productName: "string"...", I'd have productName: product.name and productPrice: product.price ...
This is my product.services.ts:

```
    export class ProductService {
  
  products: Product[] = [
    new Product(1, 'Product 1', 'P1 description', 100, 'image1.png'),
    new Product(2, 'Product 2', 'P2 description', 300, 'image2.jpg'),
    new Product(3, 'Product 3', 'P3 description', 50, 'image3.png'),
    new Product(4, 'Product 4', 'P4 description', 20, 'image4.jpg'),
    new Product(5, 'Product 5', 'P5 description', 400, 'image5.jpg'),
    new Product(6, 'Product 6', 'P6 description', 40, 'image6.jpg'),
  ]

  constructor() { }

  getProducts(): Product[] {
    return this.products
  }

}
```

And my cart-item.components.ts:

```
export class CartItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() cartItem: any

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

}

Messenger Service:

```
    export class MessengerService {    
subject = new Subject()    
constructor() { }    
sendMessage(product: Product) {     
this.subject.next(product)   
}    
getMessage() {     
return this.subject.asObservable()   
} 
}
```

Comment: What does `this.message.getMessage()` return? Most probably it is not an rxjs Observable, this is why the `subscribe` throws an error.

Comment: This is my messages.service.ts file:
`export class MessengerService {

  subject = new Subject()

  constructor() { }

  sendMessage(product: Product) {
    this.subject.next(product)
  }

  getMessage() {
    return this.subject.asObservable()
  }
}`

Comment: Hm.. the return value of `getMessage()` seems to be ok, which line throws the `No overload matches this call` error?

Comment: In my cart.component.ts: https://i.imgur.com/SadOOSd.png

Comment: Could you please try to add in the `MessengerService` the `Product` type as generic parameter for the `Subject` instantiation? I mean `subject = new Subject<Product>()`.

Comment: That's fixed it! Thank you

Comment: Perfect! Please update the question with the code of the original `MessengerService` and accept the answer below. :) This way it will be easier to understand for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `MessengerService` as the `Subject` is instantiated with the `new` operator the generic type parameter needds to be added.  The original `subject = new Subject()` should be changed to `subject = new Subject<Product>()`, this way when the `Subject` is converted to an `Observable` with `this.subject.asObservable()`, the returned type will be `Observable<Product>`. This way the `getMessage()` method has the correct return type and the `subscribe` method won't show any errors.